# formulario dinámico de control de actividades

Tags: php, html5

En una vista hay un formulario con un `textbox` el cual registra una actividad en la *base de datos* para un determinado usuario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En otro pagina esta actividad se muestra junto con otras actividades en una lista y para verificar dicha actividad se tiene q adjuntar un archivo de comprobante

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto no es una página para hacerte los deberes, aquí ayudamos a la gente a solucionar errores específicos, deberías mirar la seccion como preguntar. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @cocuca_mana Bienvenido. la pregunta no deja claro cual es el problema y todavía le falta mucha información. Y otra cosa es mejor poner código que haz hecho hasta el momento para poder ayudarte y que  puedan aceptar esta pregunta por la comunidad.

Comment: lo q coloque como tal es el marco de todo lo q quiero hacer la duda es mas q todo en adjuntar un tipo de archivo y validar con un checkbox.

Comment: Aunque la duda esté clara, siempre es conveniente que pases el código que has probado para poder ayudarte a arreglarlo, en caso de que no tengas código probado, te invito a que hagas tus propias pruebas, para tener una base sólida donde apoyar tu duda. De todas formas la duda que propones es referente a validación de formularios, te aconsejo que empieces por ahí :) Espero que estos consejos sean de utilidad.